# Who is the "timelord"?

Tags: angel-n-devil

On the show *Angel 'N' Devil*, Kou Chi is frequently mentioned as working for a "timelord" (I'm not sure about the original Chinese word). Chi An possibly works for the same group. Later, the Bad Girls become deputized by this same individual. While we eventually see Gabriel, the timelord never appears on-screen.

Who and what is the timelord? Are they extradimensional like Chi An? Are they actually associated with time in some sense?

Comment: I'm wondering if the show makes more sense in the original Mandarin(?). Dubbed shows tend to be incredibly loosely translated, often missing out entire concepts and themes

Comment: @Valorum - I haven't had the opportunity to learn much Mandarin yet. :( Sure, the "timelord" could be something totally different, and have nothing to do with time as such. But whatever the actual meaning of "timelord," based on context it's safe to say it's not the president of Taiwan, but someone in charge of an organization that spans multiple dimensions.

Comment: @Valorum - One thing to bear in mind is that the show has a lot of comedic elements. So some of the stuff is not meant to make  sense, and may even be jokes and pop culture references. For instance, the class that the main characters are in is the "Lazy Class" or "Learn-Nothing Class." This doesn't seem to be a matter of a bad translation but rather meant to be humorous. So whatever the orginal of "timelord" was might have actually been meant to sound silly.

Comment: Or when the translation talks about "the whatever spirit or soul thing," I don't think this is an incredibly awkward translation, but rather probably was equally vague in the original (for humor), since there are, say, scenes based around it being vague.